# How can I use the Freelinking module for creating links to external sites?

Tags: navigation

How can I use the [Freelinking](https://www.drupal.org/project/freelinking) module in order to create links to external websites? I'd like to find an example.

What I found online says that external links should look like this:

```
[[/^http$|^ext/":site-name-here:Title]]
```

But that hasn't worked for me.

Comment: "hasn't worked for me" is pretty useless statement. What happened when you did it?

Comment: Where did you find this online documentation? For the record, it is quite wrong, so using this syntax will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever documentation you've "found online" is wrong.

[**Freelinking**](https://www.drupal.org/project/freelinking) does not use (or understand) regular expressions.  The [module's documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2468135#extlinks) tells you that this is how you link to an external site:

```
[[http://site-name-here|Title]]
```

It also works using "https" instead of "http".

Answer (score 0):

The indicator for an external address is `http`, not `/^http$|^ext/"`. I think MathJax gave me some problems on the page.